# An algorithm to calculate foreign residence without enumerating days?

Tags: algorithm, days

The visa conditions for a country to which I travel frequently include this restriction:

"You may reside in [country] for a maximum of 90 days in any period of 180"

Given a tentative list of pairs of dates (entry and exit dates), is there an algorithm that can tell me, for each visit, whether I will be in or out of compliance, and by how many days?

Clearly, one way to do this would be to build a large array of individual days and then slide a 180-day window along it, counting residence days. But I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant method which doesn't involve building a great long list of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal algorithm for this is basically a greedy algorithm, though it could also be seen as a 1D dynamic progamming algorithm. Basically, rather than sliding the window 1 day at a time, you slide it 1 starting-date at a time. Like so:

```
first_interval = 0
last_interval = 0
for first_interval = 0 to N:
    # include more intervals as long as they (partially) fit within 180 days after the first one
    while last_interval < N and A[last_interval].start - A[first_interval].start < 180:
        last_interval += 1
    calculate total number of days in intervals, possibly clipping the last one
```

The need to clip the last interval makes it a bit less elegant than it could otherwise be: in similar algorithms, rather than summing the total each time, you add to it for added-on intervals (when incrementing last_interval) and subtract from it for left-behind intervals (when incrementing first_interval). You could do something kind of similar here with the second-to-last interval, but unless you're in a serious performance bind it's probably best not to.

Answer (score -1):

The following C++ code calculates the duration between two arbitrary dates no earlier than Jan 1, 1 A.D. in O(1) time. Is this what you're looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int days(int y,int m,int d){
    int i,s,n[13]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    y+=(m-1)/12; m=(m-1)%12+1; if(m<1) {y--; m+=12;}
    y--; s=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400; y++;
    if(y%4==0 && y%100 || y%400==0) n[2]++;
    for(i=1;i<m;i++) s+=n[i]; s+=d; return s;
}
int main(){
    cout<<days(2017,8,14)-days(2005,2,28)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can use the `days()` function to map all dates of entry and exit to integers and then use the Sneftel's algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have libraries to do the actual date calculations.